# SWRevealViewController push to actual navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm working with SWRevealViewController and I want to push a view controller from my menu view controller to actual navigation view controller. The problem is, when I use `self.revealViewController().frontViewController.navigationController!` this navigation Controller is always nil and should't be, because I always pushFrontViewController with navigation controller.

Any point how to push on actual navigation controller? I'm working with storyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution

From Menu to Normal ViewController by using Swrevealviewcontroller "**setFrontViewPosition**"

In **Swift**

```
        let obj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: obj)
        navController.setViewControllers([obj], animated:true)
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewController(navController, animated: true)
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.Left, animated: true)
```

In Objectctive-c

```
 -(void)main{
     LoginViewController *tar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
     UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tar];
     [navController setViewControllers: @[tar] animated: YES];

    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
}
```

Comment: Can you navigate the SWReveal from a UIAlert instead of the menu?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to call UINavigationcontroller of your UINavigationcontroller

revealViewController().frontViewController gives me UINavigationcontroller already

I have this in side menus controller and its working

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    var controller: UIViewController?
    var navController: UINavigationController?

    if identifier.hasSuffix("Orders")  {
        controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShowOrdersViewController") as! ShowOrdersViewController
        (controller as! ShowOrdersViewController).orderType = identifier
        navController = revealViewController().frontViewController as! UINavigationController
    }

    self.revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true)
    navController?.pushViewController(controller!, animated: true)

    return false
}
```